# Click event not detected after changing canvas overlay visibility

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-umg

I have a mobile phone interface (below image) and I want to switch between different views - in this case overlays - depending on where you click.

[image]

Click events in the first view are detected, then it switches to the second view. However once I'm in the second view click are not triggered anymore. However hovered events are still, as you can see on the below image.

[image]

By default the hidden views are set to "Collapsed" (I also tried "Hidden"), so my blueprint is toggling between "Visible" (I also tried "Not Hit Testable self-only") and "Collapsed" depending on the clicked button.

Here is my UMG setup:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the press event is triggered, a "Press Pointer Key" node is required to delegate the press event to UMG (for UI in world space).

My issue was that I forgot to add a "Release Pointer Key" node when the release event is triggered. Therefore my click was only detected the first time then not released to detect the further clicks.

Also, a cleaner way to achieve above example is to add a "Widget Switcher" to switch between the three screens (canvas).

...in case someone got the same issue as me.